# Puppeteer cannot locate selector on heroku, but works locally

Tags: javascript, heroku, web-scraping, puppeteer

I'm trying to retriteve the current page number from the pagnination at the bottom of [this page](https://www.realtor.ca/map#ZoomLevel=14&Center=43.744046%2C-79.406789&LatitudeMax=43.76832&LongitudeMax=-79.36641&LatitudeMin=43.71977&LongitudeMin=-79.44717&view=list&CurrentPage=1&Sort=6-D&PropertyTypeGroupID=1&PropertySearchTypeId=1&TransactionTypeId=2&PriceMax=1500000&BuildingTypeId=1&Currency=CAD).

My code works on my local machine, but when deplyoing to Heroku I get the following error:

> (node:23) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Error: failed to find element matching selector "#ListViewPagination_Bottom > div > div > span > span.selection > span"

Here's my code:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(
    "https://www.realtor.ca/map#ZoomLevel=14&Center=43.744046%2C-79.406789&LatitudeMax=43.76832&LongitudeMax=-79.36641&LatitudeMin=43.71977&LongitudeMin=-79.44717&view=list&Sort=6-D&PropertyTypeGroupID=1&PropertySearchTypeId=1&TransactionTypeId=2&PriceMax=1500000&BuildingTypeId=1&Currency=CAD"
  );
  let currentPageNumber = await page.$eval(
    "#ListViewPagination_Bottom > div > div > span > span.selection > span",
    (element) => element.innerText
  );
  console.log(currentPageNumber);
  await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: try to fetch on production just the `#ListViewPagination_Bottom`, console log it, and see if you get anything.

Comment: It returns null on production. On my local version, it returns the correct data. Any idea what's going on?

Comment: I would guess it's related to headless: true/false. Try: `await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});`, it might work.

Comment: No luck. This just causes the whole program to crash on Heroku.

Comment: did you ever get this figured out?